# Check if text contains a space

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

So I am asking the user to type in some text and store it as a variable-

```
 string text;
 Console.WriteLine("Please enter some text");
 text =  Console.ReadLine();
```

Then check if the user input contains a space.
If it does output the first word.

I'm not sure how to check if the sting 'text' contains a space.

Any suggestion much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To check if a string contains a space, you can use a regex, i.e.:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(text, @"\s")) {
    // text contains a space
} else {
    // text doesn't contain a space
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just try this:

```
// This will split the string on spaces.
var splitted = text.Split(' ');

// If the length of the resulting array is greater than 1
// that means that in the text is contained at least one space.
if(splitted.Length>1)
    return splitted[0];
```

Comment: Thanks Christos, but where would I place my text, to ask for the user input?

Comment: You welcome Peter. You already ask here `Console.WriteLine("Please enter some text");
 text =  Console.ReadLine();` from the user to give her input. Isn't this correct?